# MongoError: auth fails with mongoose on openshift

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, openshift

I have the following connection pattern and receiving "MongoError: auth fails". Maybe is a problem with the mongoose version? Openshift has MongoDB 2.4 and RockMongo 1.1  Thanks.

```
// Connection URL
var connection_string = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/my_app';

if(process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_PASSWORD){
  connection_string = process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_USERNAME + ":" +
  process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_PASSWORD + "@" +
  process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_HOST + ':' +
  process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_PORT + '/' +
  process.env.OPENSHIFT_APP_NAME;
}

// Connect to mongodb
var connect = function () {
    mongoose.connect(connection_string);
};
connect();
var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('disconnected', connect);
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by uninstalling RockMongo 1.1 and creating again the database directly from the mongodb shell. And changed the connection string to:

```
 var db_name = 'database_name';
if(process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_URL){
  var mongodb_connection_string = process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_URL + db_name;
}
 // Connect to mongodb
var connect = function () {
    mongoose.connect(mongodb_connection_string);
};
connect();

var db = mongoose.connection;

db.on('error', function(error){
    console.log("Error loading the db - "+ error);
});

db.on('disconnected', connect);
```